# Drag'n Drop Problems with extended glass border

Tags: wpf, border, drag, aero, aero-glass

I'm playing around with the glass border in WPF and I've found a problem.
When I extend the glass border of a window, the drag and drop functions won't work anymore... for example dragging a GridSplitter around ends with an exception.

The XAML of my MainWindow:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="ChromeDragDrop.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChromeDragDrop"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
            <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <shell:WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="-1" ResizeBorderThickness="4" CaptionHeight="36"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="50">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
        <Border Background="Lime" Opacity="0.8"></Border>
        <Border Background="Gray" Opacity="0.8" Grid.Row="1"></Border>
        <GridSplitter Background="Red" Height="10" ShowsPreview="True"  ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"></GridSplitter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Controls.GridSplitter.OnDragDelta(DragDeltaEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.GridSplitter.OnDragDelta(Object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseMoveThunk(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at ChromeDragDrop.App.Main() in C:\Project\CSharp\Learn\WPF\ChromeGlass\ChromeDragDrop\ChromeDragDrop\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding an `AdronerDecorator` at the root of your window? I was getting the same exception, but in my case my WPF control was hosted within an `HwndSource` in an MFC window. See [this MS knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955940/de) for more information.